# Access violation writing location 0x00000000 when reading/writing to vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I need to convert Java alghoritm into C++. I'm having a hard time doing this, because C++ is definitely not my language, it's much harder and illogical sometimes compared to Java. (At least for me, full-time Java developer).

Anyway, I failed. Code is almost identical to Java in terms of logic, and still doesn't work :( The worst part was converting traditional Java arrays to C++'s `vector<int>`. And I think I messed up here.

This is my C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double calculate(int n, int k, vector<int>& values);

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", calculate(7, 4, vector<int>{ 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2 }));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

double calculate(int n, int k, vector<int>& values) {
    int amount = k;
    int offset = 0;
    int predictions = (n - k) + 1;

    vector<vector<int>> arrays;

    int index = 0;
    while (predictions > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < predictions; i++) {
            vector<int> arr;

            for (int y = 0; y < amount; y++) {
                arr[y] = values[offset + y]; // HERE IS THE ERROR!!!
            }

            arrays[index] = arr;
            offset++;
            index++;
        }
        amount++;
        offset = 0;
        predictions--;
    }
    vector<double> averages;
    for (size_t a = 0; a < arrays.size(); a++) {
        vector<int> arr = arrays[a];

        int sum = 0;
        for (int value : arr) 
            sum += value;

        averages[a] = (double)sum / (double)arr.size();
    }
    double biggestAverage = 0;
    for (double average : averages) {
        if (average > biggestAverage)
            biggestAverage = average;
    }
    return biggestAverage;
}
```

And Java code here: (works flawlessly)

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    private static final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calc(7, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2));
    }

    public static double calc(int n, int k, int... values) {
        int amount = k;
        int offset = 0;
        int predictions = (n - k) + 1;

        int[][] arrays = new int[n * n][n];

        int index = 0;
        while (predictions > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < predictions; x++) {
                int[] arr = new int[amount];

                System.arraycopy(values, offset, arr, 0, amount);

                //CLEAR CODE!!! WORKS TOO!!!
                //for (int y = 0; y < amount; y++) {
                //    arr[y] = values[offset + y];
                //}


                arrays[index] = arr;
                offset++;
                index++;
            }
            amount++;
            offset = 0;
            predictions--;
        }
        double[] averages = new double[arrays.length];
        for (int a = 0; a < arrays.length; a++) {
            int[] arr = arrays[a];

            int sum = 0;
            for (int anArr : arr)
                sum += anArr;

            averages[a] = (double) sum / (double) arr.length;
        }

        double biggestAverage = 0;
        for (double average : averages) {
            if (average > biggestAverage)
                biggestAverage = average;
        }
        return Double.valueOf(
                df.format(biggestAverage)
                        .replace(",", "."));
    }

}
```

Full error stacktrace (C++):

```
Exception thrown at 0x010C10B5 in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

Comment: Why did you use a `vector` instead of a plain array as you did with java?

Comment: You can't convert Java code into a C++ code if you don't know the C++ language. Converting by guessing is no way to go. Especially with C++.

Comment: @BackSlash Because you can't in C++ do `int[n]` and it's pretty important here. `vector` as far I know don't have constant size.

Comment: Where do you specify the vector's size?

Comment: @SocketByte - Of course you can. `int[n]` does have a constant, known size. [Demo here](https://ideone.com/7Tsri1)

Comment: @BackSlash copied the demo and getting `expression must have a constant value
the value of parameter "parameter" cannot be used as a constant`

Comment: @BackSlash, that's a **non standard** runtime-sized array

Comment: @SocketByte As you can see the demo is working. Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I didn't say it's standard. I said it's possible to do it.

Comment: @BackSlash: Runtime-sized arrays are not C++. It's not surprising that you can do non-C++ things with non-C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate the vector elements before assigning values to them, when you do

```
vector<int> arr; // defines an empty vector.
arr[y] = ...     // access element at position y.
```

`arr` here is empty, pointing to a zero array, you are trying to write at memory 0x0000.

Checkout [vector documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), to see the different ways to initialize it.

In C++ you need to handle your memory, you cannot just port code from  different higher-level languages.

---

There are different ways to do it, for instance

```
vector<int> arr;
arr.reserve(amount);
for (int y = 0; y < amount; ++y) {
  arr.push_back(values[offset + y]);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Used `push_back()` instead of standard `arr[y] = smth` and it works flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: Do not do `push_back` without doing a `reserve` before! This creates so many unnecessary allocations, you know the final size of the vector before hand

Comment: You mean something like that? `arr.reserve(amount)`?

Comment: @nsubiron: It doesn't create "so many unnecessary" allocations, because `push_back` already has the liberty to reserve more memory than currently needed. @SocketByte: `reserve` is probably completely unnecessary premature optimisation here.

Comment: @ChristianHackl `push_back` will tipically duplicate the size of the vector when need it so it gives an amortized constant time. Every time it duplicates the vector creates a new bigger array and copies values there. It's not so bad as it's amortized constant time, but you can end up doing several allocations and copies. If you know the final size before-hand, you can reserve that size and do a single allocation and zero copies.

Comment: @nsubiron: That's all true, but really irrelevant if you are not dealing with huge vectors that slow down your program so much that you can actually measure the difference. The OP already struggles with C++, why complicate his learning even more with such a rarely needed low-level optimisation?